# Order of actions in find command

Tags: linux, find, command

This is the action I want to take place:

```
find ~ -type f -not -perm 0600 -ls
```

But when I try to write it this way

```
find ~ -ls \( -type f -not -perm 0600 \)
```

In which I tried to override the evaluation sequence via () operators the -ls test option always performed before the evaluation of the expression in the parenthesis,the question is doesn't parenthesis have effect on test options of find command or what?

Comment: No. Parentheses are for grouping. Order is always left to right.

Comment: You only need parentheses if you're mixing `AND` and `OR` options.